# Drawables from InputStream changing with ViewFlipper

Tags: android

I have a tabbed application, which has 5 tabs. The images in the application are taken from web call, so in tab1 for example, the first activity, makes a web call which returns the images. I am using this code

```
    urln = new URL("http://10.84.4.2:8083/imageFolder/General/backgroundcurved.png");
    con = (HttpURLConnection) urln.openConnection();
    is = con.getInputStream();
    curvedBG = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "CurvedBG");
    is.close();
```

This retrieves the image just fine, and it does so with all the images. However, I have noticed a rather annoying problem that I can't seem to fix. The image size seems to change when I flip away from the view, then flip back.

At first I thought it was a problem with the images online. So to confirm that, I changed it so instead of the images coming from online, they come from offline in the drawable folder. So I did this

```
    Drawable test;
InputStream testStream;

Resources res = getResources();
    test = Drawable.createFromStream(res.openRawResource(R.drawable.backgroundcurved), "test");
```

(For the time being, I made these global variables just so all the activities can call these images)

However same problem occurs. But the problem gets even stranger than that. In tab one, you can access a settings screen, and from there you can flip to menu 1, or menu 2. If menu one uses the test drawable, then it works fine, however if both menu 1 and menu 2 make use of this test drawable, then if I flip to menu 1, back to settings, then to menu 2, back to settings, then to menu 1, then the second time I access menu 1, the drawable has shrunk itself down to half its size, and yet images on menu 2 are fine. If I do that in reverse, i.e. access menu 2, then menu 1, then menu 2 again. Then the images in menu 2 mess up, yet the images in menu 1 are fine.

I am simply at a loss as to why this is occurring. Is there something with too many pages calling the same Drawable? Or is this a problem with viewflipper screwing up the images?

Would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction

Edit:

I also tried fetching the image using this method

```
    public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,
        IOException
{
    URL url = new URL(address);
    Object content = url.getContent();
    return content;
}

private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url)
{
    try
    {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As I heard that would fix the problem with sizing, but same problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed issue, had to reset the images on each page load